# In Excel's chart wizard, how can I use the arrow keys?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This has always bugged me:  In the excel chart wizard (and many other places), when you are editing ranges to be used for data (e.g., the "Values" or "Name" fields), if I try to use the arrow keys to move around within that text, it ends up moving my active cell around in the worksheet and really hosing up the field that I'm editing.  Therefore I end up using the mouse a great deal, which is slow and physically painful.

How can I make it so that my arrow key moves within the text I'm editing and not around the worksheet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `F2`.

It works in Excel 2007.  When you hit `F2` it toggles your cursor from the cell selection to the formula/line selection in either the current window or if you are not in a wizard, the formula bar.

Comment: where have you been all my life?

Comment: Glad it helped!  Check out this page for additional shortcuts in excel: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP005203781.aspx

Comment: Small point - this doesn't work on the Mac version of Office 2016

Comment: On mac, I can use Control+F/Control+B to move forward/backward, and Control+A/Control+E to go to the beginning/end